Recursively sum child's nominal to parent, on dynamic level parent-child structure
i have data look like this :

i try to sum the Nominal column to each respective parent, so it will looks like this :

i provided the sql script for the data :

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account](
    [AccountSeq] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentAccountSeq] [bigint] NULL,
    [AccountCode] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [AccountName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Nominal] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Account] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Account] ([AccountSeq], [ParentAccountSeq], [AccountCode], [AccountName], [Nominal]) VALUES (1, NULL, N'101', N'AKTIVA LANCAR', CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Account] ([AccountSeq], [ParentAccountSeq], [AccountCode], [AccountName], [Nominal]) VALUES (2, 1, N'10101', N'KAS', CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Account] ([AccountSeq], [ParentAccountSeq], [AccountCode], [AccountName], [Nominal]) VALUES (3, 2, N'1010101', N'KAS KECIL (IDR)', CAST(10000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Account] ([AccountSeq], [ParentAccountSeq], [AccountCode], [AccountName], [Nominal]) VALUES (4, 2, N'1010102', N'KAS KECIL ($$$)', CAST(15000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Account] ([AccountSeq], [ParentAccountSeq], [AccountCode], [AccountName], [Nominal]) VALUES (5, 1, N'10102', N'BANK', CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Account] ([AccountSeq], [ParentAccountSeq], [AccountCode], [AccountName], [Nominal]) VALUES (6, 5, N'1010201', N'BCA PKU AC: 220.391', CAST(20000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Account] ([AccountSeq], [ParentAccountSeq], [AccountCode], [AccountName], [Nominal]) VALUES (7, 5, N'1010202', N'BCA PKU AC: 220.279', CAST(25000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Account] ([AccountSeq], [ParentAccountSeq], [AccountCode], [AccountName], [Nominal]) VALUES (8, 1, N'10104', N'PIUTANG USAHA', CAST(30000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Account] ([AccountSeq], [ParentAccountSeq], [AccountCode], [AccountName], [Nominal]) VALUES (10, 1, N'10105', N'PIUTANG PROYEK', CAST(40000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Account] ([AccountSeq], [ParentAccountSeq], [AccountCode], [AccountName], [Nominal]) VALUES (11, NULL, N'201', N'HUTANG JANGKA PENDEK', CAST(50000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Account] ([AccountSeq], [ParentAccountSeq], [AccountCode], [AccountName], [Nominal]) VALUES (12, NULL, N'301', N'MODAL', CAST(60000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Account] OFF
GO

the last sql query i tried :

WITH cteTest AS (
    SELECT
    AccountSeq,
    ParentAccountSeq,
    AccountCode,
    AccountName,
    CAST(Nominal AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Nominal
    FROM
    [Account2]
    WHERE
    ParentAccountSeq IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
    a.AccountSeq,
    a.ParentAccountSeq,
    a.AccountCode,
    a.AccountName,
    CAST((a.Nominal + cte.Nominal) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Nominal
    FROM
    [Account2] a
    INNER JOIN [cteTest] cte ON cte.AccountSeq = a.ParentAccountSeq
)
SELECT
*
FROM
[cteTest]
ORDER BY
AccountSeq

Please can anyone help me to solve this?

can you post also what you expect your bith images seem identical

This code will work. Reverse the order of recursion, and make a aggregate at the end:
        WITH cteTest AS (
        SELECT
        AccountSeq,
        ParentAccountSeq,
        AccountCode,
        AccountName,
        CAST(Nominal AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Nominal
        FROM
        [Account] A1
        WHERE
        (AccountSeq NOT IN (SELECT ParentAccountSeq FROM [Account] WHERE ParentAccountSeq IS NOT NULL))

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
        a.AccountSeq,
        a.ParentAccountSeq,
        a.AccountCode,
        a.AccountName,
        CAST(cte.Nominal AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Nominal
        FROM
        [Account] a
        INNER JOIN [cteTest] cte ON cte.ParentAccountSeq = a.AccountSeq
    )
    SELECT
        AccountSeq,
        ParentAccountSeq,
        AccountCode,
        AccountName,
        CAST(SUM(Nominal) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Nominal
    FROM
    [cteTest]
    GROUP BY 
        AccountSeq,
        ParentAccountSeq,
        AccountCode,
        AccountName
    ORDER BY
        AccountSeq


ah, i see what i did wrong there.
turns out what i did is to add parent's nominal to child.
thank you very much!
it's solved.
